# Type conversion in function template deduction

Tags: c++

I have a template function, which generates objects according to the type `T` of its argument. It looks like

```
 template<typename T>
 container<T> foo(T t)
 {
     return container<T> { item<T>{t} };
 }
```

where `container` is a template class that contains another template class `item`.

I implemented `operator+` for `container<T>` so that containers that have the same underlying types `T` may add up.

**Now I want to make the following line work**

```
auto sum = foo("abc") + foo(std::string("def"));  // type mismatch
```

In other words, I want `foo` to generate a `container<const char *>` whenever it sees a `std::string`, or the other way round.

Of course I may explicitly overload `foo` like

```
container<const char *> foo(std::string str)
{
    return container<const char *> { item<const char *> { str.c_str() } };
}
```

But I have so many functions like `foo` that I really do not want to write an overloaded version for each of them.

This is an open design question. Any solution, suggestion, or workaround is welcome and appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: [Template specialization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-specialization-c/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a template type alias:

```
template <typename T> using bar = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, const char *>, std::string, T>;
```

Then your function becomes:

```
template<typename T>
container<bar<T>> foo(T t)
{
    return container<bar<T>> { item<bar<T>>{t} };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I've been looking for. It works, and I plan to apply this approach directly to `item`.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, the behavior you seek seems to be more specific to 
`container<T>` or `container<std::string>` than to `foo()` and its siblings. So I guess one way to achieve your goal would be to overload `operator +` at least for the `container<std::string>` case such that not only containers of the same element type can be added, but you can instead add any container of an element type that can be converted to `T` (or just `std::string`) to a `container<T>` (or just `container<std::string>`). For example, something along the lines of this:

```
template <typename U>
container<std::string> operator +(container<std::string> a, const container<U>& b)
{
    a.insert(end(a), begin(b), end(b));
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll take part of it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;
```

and add one letter:

```
auto sum = foo("abc"s) + foo(std::string("def"));
//                  ^ here
```