# Type conversion in class template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a template class `item` which stores objects of various types `T`. It also attaches attributes to those objects in instantiation/initialization.

One special thing I want to achieve is that whenever `item` sees a `const char *`, it deems and stores it as a `std::string`. This could be done, as follows.

But in type checking, I found an `item` instantiated from a `const char *` is still different in type from an `item` instantiated from a `std::string`. Please see the last line with comment `false`, which I want to make `true`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
using bar = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, const char *>::value,
                                      string, T>::type;

template<typename T>
class item
{
    bar<T> thing;

    // other attributes ...

public:
    item(T t) : thing(t) {}

    // other constructors ...

    bar<T> what() const
    {
        return thing;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = item("const char *");     // class template argument deduction (C++17)
    auto b = item(string("string"));   // class template argument deduction (C++17)

    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << (typeid(a.what()) == typeid(b.what())) << endl; // true
    cout << (typeid(a) == typeid(b)) << endl;               // false
}
```

**My question is: is it possible to make any change to the template class `item` so that an `item` instantiated from a `const char *` becomes the same in type with an `item` instantiated from a `std::string`?**

**In other words, can I make any change to the design of the template class `item` so that `typeid(a) == typeid(b)` evaluates to true ?**

Thank you !

*Note: This follows up a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235994/type-conversion-in-function-template-deduction) on template function. But I think there's something intrinsically different that it deserves a stand-alone question.*

*Edit:* My goal is to change the design of the template class `item` (e.g. `item` signatures), not the code in `main`, which is assumed to be supplied by users. I want to make life easier for the users of `item`, by not asking them to explicitly supply type `T` in instantiation. This is meant to be done by C++17 template class argument deduction or some equivalent workarounds.

**Update: Thank you all! Special thanks to @xskxzr, whose one-liner exactly solves my question. With [user-defined deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for class template argument deduction, I don't even need the `bar<T>` technique in my previous code. I put updated code below for your comparison.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class item
{
    // UPDATE: no bar<T> needed any more
    T thing;

    // other attributes ...

public:
    item(T t) : thing(t) {}

    // other constructors ...

    // UPDATE: no bar<T> needed any more
    T what() const
    {
        return thing;
    }
};

item(const char *) -> item<std::string>;  // UPDATE: user-defined deduction guide !

int main()
{
    auto a = item("const char *");     // class template argument deduction (C++17)
    auto b = item(string("string"));   // class template argument deduction (C++17)

    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << (typeid(a.what()) == typeid(b.what())) << endl; // true
    cout << (typeid(a) == typeid(b)) << endl;               // UPDATE: now true !
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the typeid's to be the same?

Comment: Thanks for the question. For some further work. To be specific, I want to have a template class `container` that contains `item<T>` with the same type `T`. And I want one `container` to hold many objects initialized from either `const char *` or `std::string`. One workaround may be to use a heterogeneous container like `boost::any`, but I want to see if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

```
item(const char *) -> item<std::string>;
```

With this deduction guide, `a` will be deduced to be `item<std::string>`.

Comment: This is the shortest and most concise answer, and it has the benefit of being correct as far as I can tell: https://godbolt.org/z/wLTrOL

Comment: Case closed! Thank you very much. This is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Nice!  There are a lot of features in C++11/17 that I'm still not aware of !

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't directly make the typeid of two templated objects using different template arguements be the same.

But to achieve your end goal you can use a factory like pattern. It could look something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename R = T>
item<R> make_item(T&& t)
{
    return item<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

// Specialization for const char *
template<>
item<std::string> make_item(const char *&& str)
{
    return item<std::string>(str);
}
```

The downside with this approach is that you'll need to construct all of your objects with this factory. And if you have a lot of exceptions you'll need to make a specialization for each exception.

Comment: I think this could be one solution! I'll try it.

Comment: Upon further examination this doesn't work as is. Please check out xskxzr's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a guess than an answer, but I'd say no.  Templates are expanded at compile time, so because you are creating an

```
item<const char*>
```

and an

```
item<std::string>
```

then the code that gets expanded looks something like

```
class item1
{
    bar<const char*> thing;

    // other attributes ...

public:
    item(const char* t) : thing(t) {}

    // other constructors ...

    bar<const char*> what() const
    {
        return thing;
    }
};


class item2
{
    bar<std::string> thing;

    // other attributes ...

public:
    item(std::string t) : thing(t) {}

    // other constructors ...

    bar<std::string> what() const
    {
        return thing;
    }
};
```

*(More or less; they wouldn't actually be called item1 and item2)*

How you chose to evaluate these two types is up to you, but to the compiler they are in fact two different types.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'd never seen or used std::conditional before so I wasn't sure what that was doing, but after reading up on it and playing around with your code I did get it to "work" by using

```
bar<T>
```

as the template type.  So instead of

```
auto a = item<const char*>("const char *");
auto b = item<string>(string("string"));
```

I did

```
auto a = item<bar<const char*>>("const char *");
auto b = item<bar<string>>(string("string"));
```

The thing is you need the template type to be the same in both cases, meaning the type needs to resolve to std::string before the template gets expanded.  As long as you use your conditional, you can define any type.

```
auto c = item<bar<int>>(5);
```

Not sure that's a good solution (which is why I said "work"), but see my other answer about the class types actually being different.

Comment: Thanks. Your code should work as you expect. But what I want is change the design of template class `item`. The code in main is meant to be supplied by users of `item`.